# Most Powerful test

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Using Neyman Pearson Lemma, find a Most Powerful test for
$H_0 : \sigma = 2$ vs. $H_1 : \sigma = 1 \ $
at level $\alpha$ based on a random sample $X_1, \dots , X_n \ $ from $N(3, \sigma^2
)$. Also suggest a Uniformly Most
Powerful test at level $α$ for $H_0 : \sigma = 2$ vs. $H_1 : \sigma < 2$.

I'm new to this topping. I have an idea with mean unknown, but with variance unknown I don't have any experience.

Comment: You start by looking at the likelihood ratio $\dfrac{ \mathbb P(\mathbf x \mid H_0)}{ \mathbb P(\mathbf x \mid H_1)}$.  What do you find in this case?

Comment: Alright after a lot of trying I solved for $\sum_1^n (x_i -3)^2 \ge \frac{2\theta'\theta''}{\theta '' - \theta '}( \frac n 2 \log \frac{\theta ''}{\theta'} - \log k ))$

Comment: can I substitute $y_i = x_i-3$ and  say $\sum_1^n (y_i )^2>C$  is chisquare distribuition and  best critical region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likelihood ratio is proportional to $\frac{\left(\frac1{\sqrt{8\pi}}\right)^n\exp(-\sum(x_i-3)^2/8)}{\left(\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)^n\exp(-\sum(x_i-3)^2/2)} = \frac1{2^n}\exp\left(\frac38 \sum(x_i-3)^2\right)$ which is an increasing function of $\sum(x_i-3)^2$

so your test is going to reject $H_0$ when $\sum(x_i-3)^2$ is too small and not reject it when $H_0$ is not too small

As you say, what constitutes *too small* can be found from a chi-squared distribution. Under $H_0$,  the distribution of $\frac{X_i-3}{2}$ should be a standard normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1$, so $\frac{1}{4}\sum(X_i-3)^2$ should have a chi-squared distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom, and since the rejection region corresponds to "too small", you want to consider the bottom tail

When extending this from $H_1: \sigma=1$ to $H_0: \sigma \lt 2$, the same arguments apply.  So again you reject when $\sum(x_i-3)^2$ is too small, and the test is exactly the same

Comment: So in this case is doesn't change anything? Uniformly most powerful changes because is not a simple test?

Comment: It will be the same uniformly most powerful for all $H_1:\sigma<2$ since you will end up with something proportional to $\left(\frac{\sigma}{2}\right)^n\exp\left(\left(\frac12 - \frac{1}{\sigma}\right) \sum(x_i-3)^2\right)$ which is still an increasing function of $\sum(x_i-3)^2$ but the actual power will change depending on the actual alternative $\sigma$

Comment: So depends on the function we find from the likelihood ratio. Got it thank you.